# Adapter notifyDataSetChanged nor working

Tags: android, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I used `notifyDataSetChanged` for adapter but my List didn't updated. Here is part of my code.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userNames);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewUsers);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

SO every time I'm adding item to `userNames` , I'm calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method, but there are no any updates. I tried many things with cleaning , clearing `userNames` but it's not working.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

EDIT:

I'm calling these two functions where I'm adding new user.

```
  userNames.add(user.getUsername());
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also I have `User` class, but I fill in `ListView` with users' usernames.

Comment: Please show more code, where you make changes to your userNames?

Comment: Thanks for response, I made an edit

Answer (score 1):

For an `ArrayAdapter`, `notifyDataSetChanged()` only works if you use the add, insert, remove, and clear functions on the Adapter.

When an ArrayAdapter is constructed, it holds the reference for the List that was passed in. If you were to pass in a List that was a member of an Activity, and change that Activity member later, the ArrayAdapter is still holding a reference to the original List. The Adapter does not know that you changed the List in the Activity.

Try this:

```
userNames.add(user.getUsername());
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(userNames);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @traninho, yes I  made the correction, by mistake I cleared the collection instead of adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Try add username directly to adapter instead of adding to userNames. Maybe when you create a new instance of ArrayAdapter, it will create a new private List inside adapter and you add username to old instance of userNames :

```
adapter.add(user.getUsername());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```